# While reading .prn file using fs.open getting error TypeError: flags must be an int

Tags: node.js, binary, readfile, barcode-printing

```
var fileBuffer = fs.open('http://www.mysite/orderworkflow/barcodefiles/fragile.prn', function (err,data) {
if (err) 
{
   return console.log(err);
}
console.log(data);
});
var jobFromBuffer = printer.printBuffer(fileBuffer, options);
var jobFromFile = printer.printFile(fileBuffer, options);
jobFromFile.cancel();
```

I am reading file from online resource and sending the same file to printer but I am getting the error like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D75aF.png)

Answer (score 2):

Second param in `fs.open` is `flags` and you gave `callback`

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback

Try this:

```
var fileBuffer = fs.open('http://www.mysite/orderworkflow/barcodefiles/fragile.prn', 'r', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(data);
});
```